# How can I join two SELECT statements?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select * 
From
(
    select * 
    from order 
    order by creationtime desc
) 
where rownum=1 and creationtime='12-feb-2010';
```

and

```
select * 
from
(
    select * 
    from 
    order by rate desc
) 
where rownum<=2 and creationtim='12-dec-2011';
```

I want to join these two `SELECT` queries, using `JOIN`. Both `SELECT` queries query from same table. I do not want use `UNION`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `UNION`?  Is this homework?

Answer (score 13):

It is hard to tell from your question what all should be in the "ON" clause below since you didn't indicate the primary key, but this should give you the idea of what you need to do.

```
select * From
(select * from order order by creationtime desc) A 
INNER JOIN (select * from order by rate desc) B
ON A.rownum = B.rownum
where A.rownum=1 and A.creationtime='12-feb-2010' 
AND B.rownum<=2 and B.creationtim='12-dec-2011'
```

Comment: the main idea of joining a table with itself is to use aliases (A and B in Michael's example)

Comment: ATR_KEY column is primary key in my table.

Comment: and one thing creation time is same for both the select statement ...thanks for replying

Answer (score 1):

Use the row_number() analytic function to get the first row for each value.

```
select [list of columns]
  from (select o.*, row_number() over (partition by creationtime)
          from order o
         where creatontime in ('12-DEC-2011', '12-FEB-2010')
       )
 where rn = 1;
```